# Сортировка двумерного массива по значениям столбца

Tags: c, массивы, сортировка

Есть массив `int pair_arr[5][1];` 
В конкретном примере он представляет табличку из чисел 6x2:

```
 12 14
 34 42
 89 75
 31 0
 9  6
 17 88
```

Задача состоит в том, что его надо отсортировать по возрастанию значений первого столбца. Т.е. результат выполнения должен быть такой:

```
9 6
12 14
17 88
31 0
34 42
89 75
```

Появилась идея - сортировать первый стоблец массива пузырьком, но при этом, во время обмена значениями, обменивать еще и соответствующие значения второго столбца(т.е. сдвигать сразу "строчку из таблицы").

Пишу на Си, `strAmount` в данной задаче - размер массива.

```
for(i = 0; i < strAmount - 1; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < strAmount - 1; j++)
        if(pair_arr[j+1][0] < pair_arr[j][0])
        {

            bufX = pair_arr[j+1][0];
            pair_arr[j+1][0] = pair_arr[j][0];
            pair_arr[j][0] = bufX;

            bufY = pair_arr[j+1][1];
            pair_arr[j+1][1] = pair_arr[j][1];
            pair_arr[j][1] = bufY;

        }
}
```

На выходе получается, что первый столбец отсортирован верно, а во втором получается что-то непонятное, причем видно, что там есть значения из первого столбца:

```
9 12
12 17
17 31
31 34
34 88
88 89
```

Не могу разобраться, в чем ошибка.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В объявлении массива следует указывать размеры, а не максимальные значения индексов: `int pair_arr[6][2];`

Comment: Ох.. Похоже, надо бы мне спать побольше. Такая дурацкая ошибка.
Благодарю!